# What happens if you append a list to itself?

Tags: python, circular-reference

What will happen if I try to append a list to itself?

```
# Let's say empty list is created.
some_list = []
# Now, append it with self
some_list.append(some_list)
# Output shows [[...]] on iPython console.
```

What does this mean? Does `some_list` become recursive list or something ? What will happen to reference count of `some_list`? How garbage collector will treat this? When this `some_list` will be garbage collected?

Comment: *Does some_list become recursive list or something* Yes. The garbage collector handles circular references, yes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you created a circular reference; the list object references itself. This means that the reference count goes up by 1 extra reference.

The Python garbage collector will handle this case; if nothing else references the list object anymore the garbage collector process is responsible for breaking that circle:

```
>>> import gc
>>> some_list = []
>>> gc.get_referents(some_list)
[]
>>> some_list.append(some_list)
>>> some_list[0] is some_list
True
>>> gc.get_referents(some_list)
[[[...]]]
```

Comment: Same thing works with `Dict` as well ? So, in general all mutable data structures in Python ?

Comment: Yes, this applies to anything that can reference its own type, including dictionaries.